# System crashed during updation to 20.04 64bits

Tags: system-installation, update-manager

My system crashed during the update to 20.04. I have 4 gb ram, 500gb hard disk on my system, which are minimum requirements for 20.04. Now when I try to on my system, it shows following message (image) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD1E2.jpg). I don't know what it means and what to do? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In the future don't update till about two months after release when 20.04.1 comes out.  From  the messages( and I am a rookie too) it seems that root is missing or misplaced.  did fstab get messed up diring the upgrade.  SUGGESTION.  Get all your files off the computer to an external drive.  Install 20.04 fresh.  Put files back.

Comment: How can I get my files off the computer. It's not even going ahead of boot option. I tried many methods, but stuck here only. Do I have to lost all my files and install a fresh version or is there some other method available?

Comment: make an install usb/dvd and start your pc in try ubuntu from there you might be able to move your files to an external drive,you can use any ubuntu version of install media for this.

Comment: Agree with above.  All is not lost.  Just do the "Try Ubunut" option.  Open the file manager.  Find your files.  Move to thumb drive or external hard drive.